# React js function not found in package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

When using  `ElvWalletClient.Item({"x":"1","y":"2"})` from `import { ElvWalletClient } from "@eluvio/elv-wallet-client";`

I receive the following error

> *eluvio_elv_wallet_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.ElvWalletClient.Item
> is not a function

When looking into the [source code](https://github.com/eluv-io/elv-media-wallet/blob/main/client/src/ClientMethods.js) I do see the method (line 338)

```
exports.Item = async function ({contractAddress, tokenId}) {
  Assert("Item", "Contract address", contractAddress);
  Assert("Item", "Token ID", tokenId);

  return await this.SendMessage({
    action: "item",
    params: {
      contractAddress,
      tokenId: tokenId.toString()
    }
  });
};
```

**Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ElvWalletClient } from "@eluvio/elv-wallet-client";

const Methods = ({client, userProfile}) => {
    const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(undefined);
    const popupClient = ElvWalletClient.Item({contractAddress: "0x48341be85e735322862d654a3f3c69854a16ccaf",itemId: "407"})
    .then(data => {
        itemData(data)

      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{itemData}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Methods
```

**Initialize Wallet**

```
ElvWalletClient.InitializeFrame({
      walletAppUrl: "https://wallet.contentfabric.io",
      target: element,
      requestor: "WWE Moonsault",
      loginOnly: true,
      darkMode: true,
      // NOTE: This should be changed to tenant slug + marketplace slug when the marketplace is published
      marketplaceId: "iq__2zMYXQ6SwRFhjAc73ppcn4RP5KX3"
    })
      .then(client => {
        SetClient(client)

        // If previously used client is present, ensure it is destroyed
        if(previousClient) {
          previousClient.Destroy();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "elv-wallet-client-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@eluvio/elv-wallet-client": "^1.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "reactSnap": {
    "inlineCss": true
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please attach `package.json` in question.

Comment: @Chandan sure  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you initialized the wallet before attempting to call that function? From your included code, it doesn't seem so.

According to the [source](https://github.com/eluv-io/elv-media-wallet/blob/main/client/src/index.js) code of this package, you shouldn't use the default constructor, but one of:

1. `InitializeFrame`: to initialize the media wallet in a new iframe
2. `InitializePopup`: to initialize the media wallet in a new window

Try one of these:

```
import { ElvWalletClient } from "@eluvio/elv-wallet-client";

// Initialize in iframe at target element
const walletClient = await ElvWalletClient.InitializeFrame({
  requestor: "My App",
  walletAppUrl: "https://wallet.contentfabric.io",
  target: document.getElementById("#wallet-target")
});
    
// Or initialize in a popup
const walletClient = await ElvWalletClient.InitializePopup({
  requestor: "My App",
  walletAppUrl: "https://wallet.contentfabric.io",
});
```

If you have initialized the wallet already and it is the value you're passing to `Method` as a prop, try calling `Item()` on `client`:

```
const Methods = ({client, userProfile}) => {
    const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(undefined)

    // Change this to const popupClient = client.Item({...})
    const popupClient = ElvWalletClient.Item({contractAddress: "0x48341be85e735322862d654a3f3c69854a16ccaf",itemId: "407"})
    
    ...
}
```

Just as a side note, since the `InitializeFrame` and `InitializePopup` methods are `async`, it may be beneficial to check whether or not the promise has resolved before attempting to call additional methods on `client`.

Comment: Hi yes, I forgot to mention I did use Initialize Frame. I updated the question.

Comment: @BuddyBob Got it, I updated the answer and hopefully this solves your problem

Comment: Great! This solved the problem.